# Google Datastore access using Service Account Keys

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GCD account within which i created a project and datastore within the latter. I downloaded the service account keys for this project and stored in my local PC.

Now, i have a simple node app running in my PC. This node app has a simple query to fetch data from google datastore created above. All i need to know is how should i configure the service account keys in my node app to gain access to datastore and the corresponding entities because i get an error like this when i try to access - "Missing or insufficient permissions."

Node app query -

```
// Adding a Sample Entity
async function quickStart() {
  // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  const projectId = 'XXX';

  // Creates a client
  const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  // The kind for the new entity
  const kind = 'xxx';
  // The name/ID for the new entity
  const name = xxxx;
  // The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
  const sampleKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

  const [entity] = await datastore.get(sampleKey);
  console.log(entity);
  }
quickStart().catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Service Account credentials change your client code to:

```
// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});
```

Comment: I can try this option but earlier, I incorrectly set the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" path variable. My node app is throwing error - "Error: The file at "C:\Masters-LUC\spring-2019\internship\service-keys\xxx.json" does not exist, or it is not a file. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Masters-LUC\spring-2019\internship\mean\mean-course\"C:'
    at GoogleAuth.createError (C:\Masters-LUC\spring-2019\internship\mean\mean-course\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:426:16)"  . What should i do to fix this error??

Comment: Specify the correct path. I would create a much shorter directory such as: `c:\google` and put your credentials file there.

Comment: There was a similar error on the other stackoverflow link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998564/unable-to-set-google-application-credentials-environment-node-js-in-windows-10   So i deleted and reinstalled npm package - google-auth-library. Later i used your suggestion/solution to run my node app. It worked. Thank you very much John

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Datastore Emulator.

Please follow the steps bellow.

`gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator`

`gcloud beta emulators datastore start`

oiutput: [datastore] Dev App Server is now running.

more details: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator